# Problem With decoding an Incoming WhatsApp message using Twilio

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, twilio-api

I use this lambda as WebHook for Twilio WhatsApp. but when I receive the message in event. it is a base64 encoded. after decoding to a string with utf-8, it's still not in proper string form.
here is the code:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    // TODO implement

   // event = JSON.stringify(event);
    console.log("Event: ", event);
    console.log("BODY", event.body);
    
    let buff = Buffer.from(event.body, 'base64');
    let text = buff.toString('utf-8');

    console.log("Text Before ", text);

    // 

    let array = text.split('&');
    
    console.log({array});
    
    let text2 = unescape(array[6]);
    let replaced = text2.split('+').join(' ');

    console.log("New Text ", replaced);
    console.log("New Text2 ", text2);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(text) );
    // console.log({array});

    //console.log("Message Body", );
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(),
    };
    return response;
};
```

the Original Message

```
Hello, From the Other Side
```

the text I got in the lambda event base64 encoded
`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`

After Decoding to string i get this.

```
Hello%2C+Form+the+Other+side.
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the body is being delivered as form encoded parameters and you are using a naive decoding method. Node.js (and the browser) has a built in way to do this, the `URLSearchParams` object.

You can use it to decode the string into the key/value pairs and then `get` the key that you need like this:

```js
const buff = Buffer.from(event.body, "base64");
const formEncodedParams = buff.toString("utf-8");
const urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(formEncodedParams);

const body = urlSearchParams.get("Body");

console.log(body);
// => "Hello, Form the Other side."
```